# Speech recognition, dictation in the Russian language

Tags: typography

When I need to type in English on Word, I usually rely on speech recognition to save me the hassle of manual typing. Can we dictate in the Russian language into Microsoft Word in the same way? Officially, Windows doesn't seem to support the Russian language for speech recognition.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about the language, but ask about software features.

Comment: If Microsoft has that support, the right way to know about that is to go to their official page and look for it - any info on this site would inevitably be out of date at the very least, and if we say "no" - then it will be wrong as soon as they add the support.